# Vuex Watch for dynamic change value

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a vuex store which is dynamically populated like so

```
state: {
    collector: {
        tableName: {
            columnName1 : 2,
            columnName2 : 'NO',
            columnName3 : '2019-03-23'
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

All my component store it's table name && columnName in `props`, so In my component I have access to `tableName` and `columnName`.

Now, onChange of `componentA(columnName1)` the value of `componentB(columnName3)` changes and the vuex value gets changed. I do something like this to change the value of vuex

```
this.$store.commit('setCollector', { tableName : currTableName , value : currValue , columnName : currColumnName});
```

Now, I want a way to check for the change of vuex value and update it in the `componentB(columnName3)` input box.

How can I achieve it? Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to watch a store value you can do it like this :

**in your component :**

```js
computed: {
    columnName1() {
      return this.$store.state.collector.tableName.columnName1;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    columnName1() {
      // do something when the value columnName1 changes
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. It was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vuex watchers:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#watch

But in general, you should be able to design your data flow in such ways that allows you calling these recalculations manually. Watchers and similar mechanisms can easily led to issues, f.e. with infinite loops, or inconsistent data.